# Installing Drivers from the Intel Website

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, acer, 13.04

Alright, I need to know how to install the Drivers from the  [Intel Website](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm), I have tried running the Shell files but they launch as a text file would, so I am quite lost

The computer in which the Driver is being installed on is a [Acer Aspire 5733Z-4633](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/acer-aspire-5733z-4633/4505-3121_7-35167954.html)

- My Specs as of now
- Ubuntu 13.04
- Intel IronLake Mobile
- 3.5 GiB Usable Ram
- Intel® Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @ 2.13GHz × 2
- OS type: 64-bit

Comment: I am asking because it is not the driver I need, the Iron Lake driver has OpenGL 2.0 when I need to have OpenGL 3.0 to run some of the programs I wish to use.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, there are certain cases where users will want or need to install the drivers directly from intel.